# Swap limbs of a skinned mesh

Tags: 3d-meshes, skeletal-animation

If I have a model, such as a robot, I am able to swap its limb meshes out and replace them with other robot limb meshes by merely removing the limb mesh from the skeleton and attaching the new one to the appropriate bone.

Now I want to essentially do the same thing but with a skinned mesh, say a human/monster character. For example I want to swap a normal human arm for some bad-ass demon arm. How do I go about doing this as I believe I need to take into account skin/bone weights etc.

Didn't Spore do something similar? Although my skeleton would be predefined as opposed to the ones created in Spore.

Comment: are the meshes split into parts already? if not then i think you need todo this first

Comment: Yes the meshes would already be separate. So effectively I want to build a skinned mesh from several parts, effectively attaching them to a skeleton and stitching them together at the joints.

Comment: yeah perfectly doable then. what engine are you using?

Comment: Really? wow?! I asked this question ages ago and was met with little help. Lets say for now I'm using Unity as I want to reach out to mobile. Understandably the models would not be intricate as I imagine the process itself to be quite heavy for mobile devices. If its not doable on Unity then I'll do it the java way on android.